# EXT-JS File Upload dialog not working with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, extjs

EXT-JS 3.4

Chrome version 40.0.2214.115 m

If you go to http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/file-upload.html and try to upload a file, the 'Browse' button does not open a file browser.

This use to work. It works in FF and IE.  I believe this is a new issue. Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Which version of Chrome do you have?  I'm on Windows 7, not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is an upgrade for Chrome. That appears to fix it.  This was on a Windows 7 box, not sure if that would make a diffference or not. But its working now with the upgrade.